# Why this simple showMessage dialog identifier is not found here

Tags: user-interface, freepascal

I am using following simple code from [here](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Dialog_Examples#ShowMessage):

```
program LazMessage;
uses 
  Dialogs;
begin
  ShowMessage('This is a message from Lazarus');
end.
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
 fpc gui_showmsg.pas 
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling gui_showmsg.pas
gui_showmsg.pas(6,3) Error: Identifier not found "ShowMessage"
gui_showmsg.pas(9) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Adding `{$mode delphi}` or `{$mode objfpc}` does not make any difference.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: "dialogs" that uses close refers to is some console utility, it doesn't have any "ShowMessage" as the compiler explains. You wan't to use dialogs from LCL. Easiest is to use lazarus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ShowMessage` is for Lazarus and not FreePascal. So, you cannot use it in FreePascal.

Comment: How can I have simple GUI in freepascal. I am working on Debian Stable Linux and have `fpc` and `lazarus` installed. I want to create GUI from code source files rather than visually.

Comment: I have no first-hand experience with creating GUI in Free Pascal, but it seems fpGUI is what you need. http://fpgui.sourceforge.net/